# Создание новых узлов в html документе

Tags: javascript

предположим существует slide_block обвёртка и в ней уже существуют некоторое количество других div блоков

```
<div class="slide_block">
    
    <div class="slide" id="slide_2"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_3"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_4"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_5"></div>
    
</div>
```

как вставить в начало новый html элемент

```
<div class="slide" id="slide_1"></div>
```

и так же как вставить в конец новый html элемент

```
<div class="slide" id="slide_6"></div>
```

Comment: Что Вы уже попробовали сделать?

Comment: [это поможет](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#insertadjacenthtml-text-element)

Comment: Питался разобраться с теорией, но мозг не тянет, я так понял html узел нужно создавать несколькими подходами, сперва создать div а потом зарядит его содержимым, мне интересно нет ли варианта создать весь узел в том числе с содержимым разом, и самое главное узел нужно создать в строго определённых местах как я уже писал

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 2):

Предложу ещё вариант помимо предложенных вариантов @MaximLensky

```js
let mainBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("slide_block")[0];

mainBlock.innerHTML += "<div class='slide' id='slide_1'>6</div>"; 
mainBlock.innerHTML = "<div class='slide' id='slide_1'>1</div>" + mainBlock.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="slide_block">
    
    <div class="slide" id="slide_2">2</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_3">3</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_4">4</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_5">5</div>
    
</div>
```